# Sorting Issue with Underscore in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to perform sorting on below data but postgres return the wrong sorting result.

Can someone please help me over her. How can I get proper sorting data.

Here I'm write below query to get data,

```
SELECT * FROM TempTable ORDER BY a_test ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

and it's return result like below,

```
| BB001217        |
| BB001217_000010 |
| BB001217_000011 |    
| BB001217_00002  |
| BB001217_00003  |
| BB001218        |
| BB001219        |
| BB001220        |
| BB001220_000010 |    
| BB001220_000011 |    
| BB001220_00002  |    
| BB001220_00003  |
| BB001220_00004  |
| BB001220_00005  |
| BB001220_00006  |
```

And I Expected result in below form,

```
| BB001217        |
| BB001217_00002  |
| BB001217_00003  |
| BB001217_000010 |
| BB001217_000011 |    
| BB001218        |
| BB001219        |
| BB001220        |
| BB001220_00002  |    
| BB001220_00003  |
| BB001220_00004  |
| BB001220_00005  |
| BB001220_00006  |
| BB001220_000010 |    
| BB001220_000011 |
```

Comment: can you show what have you tried and what is the output?

Comment: Please do not use images. We cannot copy the data or the queries you tried for testing purposes. Please add the data as text.

Comment: Thanks S-Man I have added quey and result in text format.

Comment: What is the "proper" sorting you want? But if I had to guess you are looking for one of [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+natural-sort)

Answer (score 2):

From PostgreSQL v10 on you could use an ICU collation that provides “natural sorting”:

```
CREATE COLLATION english_natural (
   LOCALE = 'en-US-u-kn-true',
   PROVIDER = icu
);

SELECT *
FROM TempTable
ORDER BY a_test COLLATE english_natural
         ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

Comment: "english_natural" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist

Comment: @gstackoverflow You have to create it first, as exemplified by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing numbers in a VARCHAR column and the sorting is thus based on character sorting where `'10'` is considered to be smaller than `'2'`

You need to split the column into two parts, then convert the second to a number and sort on those two:

```
SELECT * 
FROM temptable 
ORDER BY split_part(a_test,'_',1),
         nullif(split_part(a_test,'_',2),'')::int ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/RNU44666